# PHP DOMElement::replaceChild produces fatal error

Tags: php, domdocument

Source HTML (test.html) is:

```
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PHP Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test page</h1>
    <div>
        <div id="to-replace-1">Test content 1</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

PHP to modify this HTML is:

```
<?php 
$str = file_get_contents('test.html');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($str);

$div1 = $doc->getElementById('to-replace-1');
echo $div1->nodeValue;  // Success - 'Test content 1'
$div1_1 = $doc->createElement('div');
$div1_1->nodeValue = 'Content replaced 1';
$doc->appendChild($div1_1);
$doc->replaceChild($div1_1, $div1);
```

Doesn't matter - append newly created $div1_1 to $doc or not. The result is the same - last line produces 'PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught DOMException: Not Found Error in ...'.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that `$doc` does not have a child which is `$div1`. Instead, you need to replace the child of `$div1`'s parent, which you can access via its [`parentNode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.parentnode) property:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$div1_1 = $doc->createElement('div');
$div1_1->nodeValue = 'Content replaced 1';

$div1 = $doc->getElementById('to-replace-1');
$div1->parentNode->replaceChild($div1_1, $div1); 
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PHP Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test page</h1>
    <div>
        <div>Content replaced 1</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/l8urE)

Note that you don't need to append `$div1_1` to the HTML, `replaceChild` will do that for you.